# WoW Style Addon Implementation

Tags: c++, direct3d, add-on, direct3d9, world-of-warcraft

I am looking for any open source implementations that allow for a creation of rendered objects like World of Warcrafts addon system. I am interested in recreating something similar in my own projects that make use of Direct3D8 and Direct3D9 but have not seen any similar projects to what WoW's addon system can handle.

I have a home-brewed method that can do partially what WoW does but nothing anywhere close to as advanced as their system(s).

Attempting to Google anything WoW related with programming gives nothing useful but addon websites for the game itself and nothing towards open source things for use in other projects.

The current method I am doing is by using primitive objects rendered via vertices and allowing sprites to override the primitive and be rendered instead. As-is, I can create UI elements like this:

[image: Addon example 1.]

This is made up of 6 different 'objects' that parent to one another.
Another example would be:

[image: Addon example 2.]

This one is made up of 3 objects, with two being overridden with a sprite.

I'm interested in seeing similar projects to compare and learn from to extend my system or start a new one from the ground up with better implementation ideas in mind.

Comment: Or are you trying to render your own graphical widgets within the game even though you don't have a formal API to do that?

Comment: @immibis - I am not looking for a GUI framework per-say, since those are going to be limited to what they can do vs. what the WoW addon system does with basic elements. I am looking for things that mimic something similar to WoW's FrameXML system.

Comment: @selbie - Sort of. I am doing my work as an injected hook for various games and am offering my own set of API and such to allow users to extend a game more with custom addons and such.

Comment: You can either come up with an entire system from scratch, or just go nuclear and use a browser, similarly to Coherent UI and Advanced Combat Tracker. I'd reconsider D3D9 though, it's a legacy API with most dev tools not working anymore.

Comment: My projects are mods/extensions that are added into existing games. Generally through injection. The use of Direct3D8/9 is because of the games use of it, not because I want to force the use of it. I inject into the existing game and use the existing framework/rendering system that is there. Also to claim nothing works with D3D9 is a pretty invalid statement to make.